# Abstract factory design pattern : issue handling abstractions

Tags: c++, design-patterns, gtkmm, abstract-factory

In a project, I have decided to try to hide all the widget toolkit details behind an [abstract factory pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/abstract-factory). The concrete widget toolkit is [`gtkmm`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gtkmm). Here is simple diagram showing the architecture I have so far:

[image: Architecture so far]

(So for now, I'm simply trying to abstract stuff away. The factory is not there yet. Eventually, it will construct the `Gtkmm3*` classes and return the corresponding interface.)

I started trying to abstract away the "containers" or "layout". In my code, I need to operate on the layouts. For example, I need to be able to register widgets in them. Using plain `gtkmm`, I would use:

```cpp
void Gtk::Grid::attach(Gtk::Widget& child, int left, int top, int width, int height);
```

which in the case of my abstractions would translate to something like this:

```cpp
void ILayout::attach(IWidget& child, int left, int top, int width, int height);
```

Implementing `ILayout::attach` is easy. I can simply `dynamic_cast` the `child` argument to the `Gtk::Widget` type and call `Gtk::Grid::attach`. This is possible because the concrete `Gtkmm3Widget` class also inherits from `Gtk::Widget`. In my code, I also need to access the specific elements inside de layout. In `gtkmm` I used the

```cpp
Gtk::Widget* Gtk::Grid::get_child_at(int left, int top);
```

call. In the case of my abstraction, this would translate to:

```cpp
IWidget* ILayout::get_child_at(int left, int top);
```

In this case, the implementation is not so simple, because I access a bare `Gtk::Widget*` but must return a (non owning) `IWidget*`, of which `Gtk::Widget` knowns nothing about. Here is the code:

```cpp
IWidget* Gtkmm3Layout::get_child_at(int left, int top)
{
    Gtk::Widget* gtkWidget = get_child_at(left, top);

    return ???
}
```

In the above code, if I construct a `Gtkmm3Widget` instance and return its address, then I will get a dangling pointer because it will be destroyed at the end of the scope.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to return the needed non-owning `Gtk::Widget*`?
2. I don't see any and I'm starting to think I have a design flaw*. If this is the case, what would be a better way to approach this?

* I have found no "real life" example of an implementation of this design pattern I could study. All I find are toy examples.

Comment: How did the child widget get there in the first place? If it's guaranteed to have been created as an `IWidget`, you can just dynamic cast again. Did you try that and get `nullptr` or what?

Comment: For some reason I thought that this would not work in the opposite direction... But now that you mention it it seems very straightforward...

Comment: @Useless You were right, using `dynamic_cast` again worked. I forgot to cast something elsewhere in the code. I should have thought about that. If you want to write an answer, I'll accept it.